# HTTP Observable subscribe working in component, but triggers error 'undefined' in template (Angular2+TS)

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm having an error that seems a bit mysterious to me. Perhaps some new sets of eyes can spot my error!

I have detail-component and a list-component, to which I retrieve data from the server. My list-component works like a charm, but I'm having trouble with the detail-component. The data from the server is correct, but when I try to print it to the browser, it gives me undefined error(cannot get name of undefined). Everything works well in the ngOnInit method, and it logs my data to the console as expected. Here is the relevant part of my code from the detail-component:

```
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() hero: Hero; //also tried without the input in front of hero

    constructor(public _routeParams: RouteParams, public _service: Service) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
        this._service.getById(id)

            .subscribe(hero => {
                this.hero = hero;
                console.log("hero: ", this.hero); //the correct data is logged!
            });     
    }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<h1>Hero: {{hero.name}}</h1>
```

As a reference the same relevant code in the list-component, that lists all heroes and works perfectly.

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    date: string;
    heroes: Array<Hero>;

    constructor(public _service: Service, public _router: Router) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    getHeroes() {
        this._service.getHeroes()
            .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes" >
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I really can't spot what's wrong in my detail-component??? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have used the elvis (?) operator in these situations: change `{{hero.name}}` to `{{hero?.name}}` so when hero is available it will print the result to the template

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm new here, and I was wondering how some questions have a green background, some don't! I didn't know you could do this. So now I know, and now it's done! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
<h1 *ngIf="hero">Hero: {{hero.name}}</h1>
```

Comment: This also works! Now I just have to figure out how to get the rest of my template working, since I have nested objects in the Hero object. But that's a whole new question!

Comment: @AJT_82 you can use the elvis operator in my answer for nested objects. For example: hero?.properties?.name will print name only if hero object has properties.

Comment: @echonax Good to know! This is of course off topic regarding the original question but: for example I call _methods_ in the same template to iterate through nested objects, here is an example of totally made up objects to showcase what I mean: `*ngFor="let animals of hero.getAnimals();` Then even further I iterate through another object of the previous object like so: `*ngFor="let dogs of animals.getDogs()"` So that makes it a bit more trickier I think...

Comment: @AJT_82 so what would be the problem here? if `hero.getAnimals()` return an array of animals, you can still print animal names with `{{animals?.name}}` if that animal have a name property

Comment: @echonax The problem occurs already in the call of the method! `cannot read property 'getAnimals' of undefined`. When I remove all from the template except the h1 with the name of the hero the `hero.name` gets printed fine, both with the elvis operator, as well as you ngif suggestion. But when I add the rest of my template it complains about hero being undefined in the call of the method. I tried wrapping the whole template with `<div *ngIf="hero"> </div>` but that gave me just errors...

Comment: @AJT_82 Well I haven't seen a similar use of `*ngFor="let animals of hero.getAnimals();` but how about elvising the hero? `*ngFor="let animals of hero?.getAnimals();` I don't know if this'd work. Usually you make the list inside your component: i.e `this.animalList = myservice.getAnimals();` and `*ngFor="let animals of animalList | async"` if getAnimals returns an observable